# How to check which files got merely hardlinked or actually copied by `rsync`?

Tags: rsync

I'm using `rsync` in the following way:

```
rsync --recursive --checksum --link-dest="previousbackup" "srcdir/" "destdir"
```

I would like to get an exact report on which files were hardlinked to an identical file in `previousbackup`, and which files got actually copied.

How can I do that?

Neither `--progress` nor `--stat` deliver this information.

I'm using `rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31`

Thanks!

Comment: Well, `-vvvv` doesn't seem to work, nor does `--debug=hlink4` - beyond that I'm not sure anything's going to tell you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Rsync` does not seem to currently provide such report.
However, you could get the wanted info after the `rsync` execution using `find` `-links` option. From [man find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

> ```
>    -links n
>           File has n hard links.
> ```

So you can get:

- the files copied (i.e. not hardlinked) from `src/`:

  ```
  find dest/ -links 1 -type f
  ```
- the files hardlinked from `previousbackup`:

  ```
  find dest/ -links +1 -type f
  ```

Note that the above presumes that `dest/` was empty before the `rsync` command, which should presumably be the case because seem to be using `rsync` to backup `src/`